# Creating dataset.json for a column family in cassandra-unit

Tags: json, unit-testing, cassandra, datastax

How can I create dataset.json for CFs with combined partition keys and clustering keys to use in Cassandra-unit ?
For example how can I define following CF there?

```
CREATE TABLE corpus.bigram_time_category_ordered_frequency (
    id bigint,
    word1 varchar,
    word2 varchar,
    year int,
    category varchar,
    frequency int,
    PRIMARY KEY((year, category),frequency,word1,word2)
);
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you are looking for here. Do you mean you want to create a json representation of a cassandra column family table? If yes then are you using this to create tables? Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to test my cassandra data insertion project with cassandra-unit. I'm following this. https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/wiki/How-to-create-a-json-dataset

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't used this myself but I found this example that mentions composite types. Clustering keys are sometimes called "composite": https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit-examples/blob/master/src/test/java/org/cassandraunit/test/json/AutomaticallyStartAndLoadExtendedJsonDataSetTest.java